# how fast is double*bool multiplication, can it be vectorized?

Tags: c++, vectorization

I am multiplying constant `vector<bool>` on different `vector<double>` many times. I wonder how fast is that, wouldn't it be faster to convert it first to `vector<double>`, so that sse can be used?

```
    void applyMask(std::vector<double>& frame, const std::vector<bool>& mask)
    {
        std::transform(frame.begin(), frame.end(), mask.begin(), frame.begin(), [](const double& x, const bool& m)->double{ return x*m;});
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what your code looks like right now?

Comment: sorry, I did not noticed vector<bool> and vector<double> were stripped to just vector.

Comment: How do you multiply a `double` with a `bool`? Set to zero if false? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem here is that the `vector<bool>` specialization *might* get in the way of any attempt by the compiler to vectorize this...

Comment: so it is better to convert it to `vector<double>` first if I am going to do this many times?

Comment: Yeah, I'll make that an answer in a min...

Comment: @user383522: if you have enough memory then it's usually worth not using `vector<bool>` at all. It occupies less cache, but eventually you trip over some problem with the packing: this is one example but there are others to do with the fact that `vector<bool>` is not a Container. Use *any other* container that has true and false values. Normally you'd pick `vector<char>`, `vector<int>` or `deque<bool>`, but `vector<double>` has an obvious advantage here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to zero parts of a `vector<double>` using a mask of `vector<bool>`.

**As it stands right now, it's not vectorizable**. Furthermore, the `vector<bool>` template specialization is going to hinder the compiler's ability to do any sort of auto-vectorization.

So you basically have two options:

**The easy way** is to indeed convert the `vector<bool>` to a `vector<double>` of corresponding zeros and ones. Then the problem reduces to simply vector-to-vector multiplication of the same datatype, which is completely vectorizable. (even auto-vectorizable)

**The harder way** (which might be faster), is to play some hacks with the [`_mm_and_pd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c4sw98t.aspx) or [`_mm_blendv_pd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513997.aspx) intrinsics/instructions. But that requires a lot more work since you have to manually vectorize the code.

---

I suggest you just go with the easy way. No need to dive into manual vectorization unless you really need to.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both, your function as in your question, and this one:

```
void applyMask(std::vector<double>& frame, const std::vector<bool>& mask)
{
    std::transform(frame.begin(), frame.end(), mask.begin(), frame.begin(), [](const double& x, const bool& m)->double{ return m?x:0.0;});
}
```

I also tried changing the vector of bool to double to see the difference between each option.

Finally, I propose a different algorithm altogether since I think a better one can be used in this circumstance.

1. **Multiplication**

   The `xmm0` variable is an SSE register. But it's just used to do work on doubles not to parallelize.

   ```
    b0e:       8b 50 08                mov    0x8(%rax),%edx
    b11:       66 0f ef c0             pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
    b15:       48 83 c6 10             add    $0x10,%rsi
    b19:       48 83 c0 08             add    $0x8,%rax
    b1d:       31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
    b1f:       83 e2 01                and    $0x1,%edx
    b22:       f2 0f 2a c2             cvtsi2sd %edx,%xmm0
    b26:       f2 0f 59 46 f8          mulsd  -0x8(%rsi),%xmm0
    b2b:       f2 0f 11 46 f8          movsd  %xmm0,-0x8(%rsi)
    b30:       83 c1 01                add    $0x1,%ecx
    b33:       ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
    b38:       48 d3 e2                shl    %cl,%rdx
    b3b:       48 85 10                test   %rdx,(%rax)
    b3e:       66 0f ef c0             pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
    b42:       0f 95 c2                setne  %dl
    b45:       83 f9 3f                cmp    $0x3f,%ecx
    b48:       0f b6 d2                movzbl %dl,%edx
    b4b:       f2 0f 2a c2             cvtsi2sd %edx,%xmm0
    b4f:       48 8d 56 08             lea    0x8(%rsi),%rdx
    b53:       f2 0f 59 06             mulsd  (%rsi),%xmm0
    b57:       f2 0f 11 06             movsd  %xmm0,(%rsi)
    b5b:       0f 85 17 01 00 00       jne    c78 <main+0x298>
   ```

   This is about 22 instructions. The `jne` is the loop branch. It is repeated 8 times because the loop was unrolled that many times. This is also why I say "about 22 instructions". It will vary depending on the repeat.
2. **Ternary Operator**

   In this case, we select the value when the Boolean is true. That adds one branch which means the code may run at different speeds depending on how many flags are true or false.

   ```
    a83:       83 c1 01                add    $0x1,%ecx
    a86:       ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
    a8b:       48 d3 e2                shl    %cl,%rdx
    a8e:       48 85 10                test   %rdx,(%rax)
    a91:       66 0f ef c0             pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
    a95:       74 05                   je     a9c <main+0xbc>
    a97:       f2 0f 10 45 08          movsd  0x8(%rbp),%xmm0
    a9c:       83 f9 3f                cmp    $0x3f,%ecx
    a9f:       f2 0f 11 45 08          movsd  %xmm0,0x8(%rbp)
    aa4:       48 8d 55 10             lea    0x10(%rbp),%rdx
    aa8:       0f 84 d4 01 00 00       je     c82 <main+0x2a2>
   ```

   That being said 11 instructions per loop is much reduced. The second `je` is for the loop, just like the code above.
3. **Two Vectors of Doubles**

   On the other hand, when we use double we avoid the conversion as in (1) and if the same masks are used over and over again and if your vectors are rather large, it's going to be a great optimization:

   ```
   a9d:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
   a9f:   66 41 0f 2e 44 24 28    ucomisd 0x28(%r12),%xmm0
   aa6:   0f 9a c2                setp   %dl
   aa9:   0f 45 d0                cmovne %eax,%edx
   aac:   f2 0f 59 4b 20          mulsd  0x20(%rbx),%xmm1
   ab1:   f2 0f 11 4b 20          movsd  %xmm1,0x20(%rbx)
   ab6:   66 0f ef c9             pxor   %xmm1,%xmm1
   aba:   f2 0f 2a ca             cvtsi2sd %edx,%xmm1
   ```

   This is 8 instructions! And we do not see the branch. But that's part of the optimization. There should be at least one branch, so it would be 9 instructions.

   So it looks like Mysticial had the correct answer. I did not try to see how fast each set of instructions would take, though. And this is not parallelized. If you wanted full parallelization, you'd certainly have to write it in assembly or at least use intrinsics.
4. **Assembly**

   With AVX, you can load 8 doubles with a mask at once:

   ```
     8a3:   b8 a5 ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffa5,%eax
     8a8:   c5 f9 92 c8             kmovb  %eax,%k1
     8ac:   62 f1 fd 49 28 85 50    vmovapd -0xb0(%rbp),%zmm0{%k1}
     8b3:   ff ff ff
   ```

   In this example, I put an 8-bit mask in `%eax` (0xA5), I copy that in `%k1` and then I load a value from `-0xb0(%rbp)` to `%zmm0` masking the doubles (setting them to all zeroes) wherever the corresponding mask bit is `0`.

   You would need one more instruction to save the `%zmm0` back to memory, two instructions to increase your pointers, and one counter and a branch. So 8 instructions instead of 9 * 8 = 72 in the best case in C++. No multiplication, a single very fast conversion (`kmovb`). The one constraint: your arrays need to have a size which is a multiple of 8.

   You could also use the intrinsic, something like so:

   ```
    #include <immintrin.h>

        __mmask8 mask = 0xA5;
        __m512d a, b;

        __m512d res = _mm512_mask_blend_pd( mask, a, b );
   ```

   You'll have to check the docs. One of a or b is not used.

   Note that this is an "integer" instruction. It works with doubles because we either load the 64 bits as is or set it to all zeroes which is the same as `(double)0`.
5. **Understanding the algorithm**

   Thinking about your problem a little more, I also noticed the fact that what you're trying to do is save some zeroes in an array. You could do that differently and avoid a complete load / multiple / save cycle.

   The closest C++ algorithm to support that functionality is [std::replace_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace). The problem is that the test is against the same array values as the input being replaced. So in your case it wouldn't help.

   The `std::replace_if` algorithm looks like this:

   ```
    template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate, class T>
    void replace_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last,
                    UnaryPredicate p, const T& new_value)
    {
        for (; first != last; ++first) {
            if(p(*first)) {
                *first = new_value;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   In your case, you need two inputs and the `new_value` is known (`0.0`) so that is not required although it will most certainly be optimized out if present. So now we can rewrite your `applyMask()` function like so:

   ```
    template<class ForwardValuesIt, class ForwardMaskIt, class T>
    void mask_if(ForwardValuesIt first, ForwardValuesIt last,
                 ForwardMaskIt mf, ForwardMaskIt ml,
                 const T& new_value = T())
    {
        for (; first != last && mf != ml; ++first, ++ml) {
            if(!*ml) {
                *first = new_value;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Here the one drawback is the `!` in the `!*ml`. I think it isn't clean. But as far as the algorithm is concerned, it makes it a lot faster. If you only mask a very few doubles, it's going to fly through a last faster than the `transform()` which does a full read/modify/write cycle.